# Cannot install ionic using npm

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

Please check the below image and give a solution for this, I am stuck, please help.

[image]

Comment: This maybe because of your internet connection, try to connect to other internet provider or other wifi and do it again

Comment: update node and npm and it will work

Comment: I have the latest version of nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally was able to fix the issue and install ionic, so I was hoping I should share it, if anyone having the same issue please check if my steps also works for you.

1. Turn off Windows Firewall
2. Turn off any/every Antivirus or windows defender you are running.
3. Clear npm cache, run - `$ npm cache clean`
4. Remove Nodejs
5. Restart PC
6. Install latest version of Nodejs
7. Clear npm cache again, run - `$ npm cache clean`
8. [important] First only install cordova, run - `$ npm install -g cordova`
9. Then install Ionic, run - `$ npm install -g ionic`

Hopefully it will work, this how I was able to fix my issue.

Comment: Hmm. Hope this is useful for everyone. But tell me what is relation between windows Firewall & npm for solving this problem.

Comment: @bipon: Windows Firewall was blocking the node and npm while I was trying to install ionic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Node JS 0.12.6 Version,
and after that, use:

```
$npm install -g cordova ionic
```

in DOS (cmd). It will install ionic and Cordova.

Comment: Not working with Nodejs 0.12.6 also. Gives me same error :(

Comment: @Pang: this solution is not working for me, any idea or alternative?